# Java Priority Queue

Tags: java, sorting, iteration, priority-queue

How would I use the priority queue built into java to read in and sort vertices of a graph, ultimately removing the minimum edge at each iteration?

Comment: The usual procedure on SO is to show what you have tried and ask a specific question about something that you don't understand.  Try posting some code to show what you've done so far.  Otherwise you'll get downvotes and the question may be closed as "not a real question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a comparator for the priority queue:

```
  class MinHeapComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
    return mDistances[one] - mDistances[two];//...
    }
  }
```

This is from a shortest path algorithm I wrote. mDistances is the distances from source to a vertex. You can modify the comparator to compare how you like.

From the documentation for Comparator: "Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

Complete documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Second, add items to the priority queue. I usually build a graph with an array containing vertex objects, each object containing a list of its adjacent vertices. So in my case I just add indices to the priority queue to represent vertices. The comparator can then contain logic to do whatever with the vertices.  PriorityQueue.add() adds items.

Third, instantiate the priority queue with the comparator:

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(numberItems, new MinHeapComparator());
```

Fourth, call PriorityQueue.poll() to extract the top item on the heap. Your comparator is used to determine what item is on the top of the heap.

Comment: Thanks. Also could you add the items to the priority queue, and then run a for loop that compares them and removes the min-edge?

Comment: If you setup the comparator to compare edge weights, calling the poll() method in a loop will remove the minimum edge at each iteration.  What algorithm are you implementing? Minimum spanning tree in the graph?

Comment: yes i have to ultimately find the mst, also i have to use a disjoint set data structure